# default focus state

Tags: android, android-theme

Why do some android devices (including the emulator) display a subtle visual indication when a `View` is focused and others don't?

The only workaround I have so far is to set `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` on focusable `View`s.

Is there any way to specify this behaviour for the whole app using the theme?

Comment: By using a selector. Check out the `focused` state and the default one.

Comment: android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground" is a selector

Comment: Curious as to why this has been downvoted